# TinyMCE execCommand return undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce, undefined

I'm trying to remove tinyMCE from a specific textarea that I have created earlier but the following command kept on producing "undefined" error (checked using firebug console):

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'textarea-plainText');
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'textarea-plainText')
```

I have initialized the TinyMCE for that particular text area using jQuery:

```
$('textarea#textarea-plainText').tinymce({
                script_url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
                oninit: function() {
                            $("textarea#textarea-plainText").tinymce().setContent("");
                            $("textarea#textarea-plainText").tinymce().setContent(noteSecContent.html[0].notesec_content);
                        }
            });
```

I have also try to add tinyMCE using the following command but it also return undefined although I have a textarea with "textarea-plainText" ID:

```
$.getScript('<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js', function() {
            window.tinymce.dom.Event.domLoaded = true;
            tinyMCE.init({
                mode: 'none'
            });
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'textarea-plainText');
        });
```

In short, I can only initialize either using the jquery method or exact method. But not using tinyMCE.execCommand. Somehow the "exeCommand" command just wont work.

HTML for the textarea:

```
<div id="plainTextModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="plainTextLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-body">
   <textarea id='textarea-plainText'></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <a href="" id="confirm-delete-note-section" class="btn btn-primary">Save</a>
    <a href="" id="confirm-delete-note-section" class="btn btn-info">Save &amp; Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's a modal, so it is initially hidden until the modal is called.

I'm using TinyMCE 4.0b1 by the way.

Comment: i am not sure, but can you try to use id swithout '-' and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes.  I tried with IDs without '-' and it still produces the same error

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle or other kind of live example?

Comment: Okay sure. I tried with the very basic implementation but the textarea is not transformed into TinyMCE as well: http://jsfiddle.net/6cPaC/1/

Did I miss something here? Or is the command "execCommand" still works for tinyMCE 4?

Comment: I guess similar init method works in version 3.5: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/tcdaab

Comment: the fiddle is crap without the tinymce lib. well, i am not used to tinymce 4 - so iam not able to tell you if the execcommand still operates

Comment: Well, I did include tinyMCE js in the external resource there. And if you change the init mode to textareas it works: mode : "textareas". Here's a screenshot of it working: http://imgur.com/G4JHNKD notice that I change the mode to 'textareas'

Comment: have a look at this fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/tcdaab/1  . it works, but don't use a beta version

Comment: exactly! I know that the execCommand works for version 3.5, however what I'm trying to do is to use the execCommand to works with TinyMCE 4 which does not work in the fiddle that I've created here: http://jsfiddle.net/6cPaC/1/ Strange.. maybe they remove the execCommmand support for TinyMCE 4?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You get undefined because in 4.x they removed `mceRemoveControl` and `mceAddControl` (I'm not sure about `mceFocus`) so use `mceAddEditor` and `mceRemoveEditor` instead.

Because these codes did the same stuff they removed `mceRemoveControl` and `mceAddControl` in the cleanup.

And also don't forget you need to use `tinymce` in lower case from now.

Comment: I tested "mceAddEditor" and it's working! It's kinda late but thank you. Here is the link to jsfiddle with working TinyMCE: http://jsfiddle.net/6cPaC/3/